# c# printing a "*" char using entered coordinates with 2d array

Tags: c#

I have been trying to do a task I recieved a few days earlier. Basically the task is a console application in C# :

Prompt the user for input of 2 coordinates in untill the word "stop" is entered. Once the word "stop" is hit, print a "*"(star char) at each of the input coordinates. The field where the coordinates are printed is 20x20. I have tried doing this, but to no avail. If somebody could help me out and show me how to store the input x,y into a 2d array, that'd be great :)

How the application should work : https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyNRq.jpg

The [0,5] [18,18]etc are the entered coordinates which are later on printed down below. The "#" chars dont need to be printed , they are here only to help with the understanding of the task.

How I tried to do it but DIDN'T work :

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{   
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool stopped = false;
        int x=0;
        int y=0;


        while (stopped)
        {
            string[,] coordinates = Console.ReadLine();
            string response = Console.ReadLine();
            response = response.ToLower();

            if (response == "STOP")
                stopped = true;
            else
            {
                string[] xy = coordinates.Split(',');
                x = int.Parse(xy[0]);
                y = int.Parse(xy[1]);

                Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
                Console.Write("*");
            }






        }


    }
    }
    }
```

The code I did just doesn't do it. It shows multiple errors that I do not know how to fix and the only thing I was able to do is get it to print a char immediately when I enter the first coordinates, instead of printing a char at every entered coordinate, AFTER the word STOP is hit.

Comment: Something that might fix a lot of your problems is I think you meant `while (!stopped)`

Comment: also you are converting your response to lower case, but then you are comparing the response to "STOP" instead of "stop"

Comment: Thanks for pointing out those mistakes guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you only need to display a matrix-style output you don't need to use `Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);`

Also you should read the user input somehow and set the proper value for the given position instead of store the coordinates.

Try this and let me know how this works for you.  You can see it also on [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SoDLcQ) fiddle. Enter the coordinates as two space-separated numbers and enter stop to print.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int x=0;
        int y=0;
        char[,] coordinates = new char[20,20];

        while (true)
        {
            //user must enter 2 3 for example.
            string[] response = Console.ReadLine().Split(new[]{" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            if (response[0].ToLower() == "stop")
                break;

            x = int.Parse(response[0]);
            y = int.Parse(response[1]);

            coordinates[x,y] = '*';
        }


        //Print the output
        for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            for( var j = 0; j < 20; j++)
                if (coordinates[i,j] == (char)0)
                    Console.Write('#');
                else 
                    Console.Write(coordinates[i,j]);

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Karel your code does indeed work, except that I had to change the for loops in output to start from 1 so it actually prints it in the correct positions. Altho when I write in 20,15 it just crashes saying that the index is out of array even tho I think its not ?

Comment: Yeap, you should validate as per your own needs. Arrays in C# are zore-based so in this case 20,15 is an invalid position as the last position is 19,19

Comment: Thanks a lot, your coding skills are really at an enviable level. :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a 20x20 2d array. Prompt the user for the x and y. Once you have each store a 1 in your array[x,y] once the user hits stop loop through the array and print '#' if null or 0 and print '*' if its a 1.

Edit, something along these lines I didn't check if this works or compiles but should get you on the right track.

```
    int[,] grid = new int[20,20];
    while (!stopped)
    {
        string[,] coordinates = Console.ReadLine();
        string response = Console.ReadLine();
        response = response.ToUpper();

        if (response == "STOP")
            stopped = true;
        else
        {
            string[] xy = coordinates.Split(',');
            x = int.Parse(xy[0]);
            y = int.Parse(xy[1]);
            grid[x,y] = 1;  
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
            {
                if (grid[i, j] > 0)
                    Console.Write("*");
                else
                    Console.Write("#");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest *decomposing* the task, cramming entire rountine into a single `Main` as bad practice; you should:

```
- ask user to enter coordinates
- print out the map
```

Let's extract the methods:

```
private static List<Tuple<int, int>> s_Points = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();

private static void UserInput() {
  while (true) {
    string input = Console.ReadLine().Trim(); // be nice, let " stop   " be accepted

    if (string.Equals(input, "stop", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
      return;

    // let be nice to user: allow he/she to enter a point as 1,2 or 3   4 or 5 ; 7 etc.
    string[] xy = input.Split(new char[] { ',', ' ', ';', '\t' },
                              StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    int x = 0, y = 0;

    if (xy.Length == 2 && int.TryParse(xy[0], out x) && int.TryParse(xy[1], out y)) 
      s_Points.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(x, y));
    else
      Console.WriteLine($"{input} is not a valid 2D point.");
  }
}
```

Printing out

```
private static void PrintMap(int size = 20) {
  // initial empty map; I prefer using Linq for that, 
  // you can well rewrite it with good old for loops
  char[][] map = Enumerable.Range(0, size)
    .Select(i => Enumerable.Range(0, size)
       .Select(j => '#')
       .ToArray())
    .ToArray();

  // fill map with points; 
  // please, notice that we must not print points like (-1;3) or (4;100) 
  foreach (var point in s_Points)
    if (point.Item1 >= 0 && point.Item1 < map.Length &&
        point.Item2 >= 0 && point.Item2 < map[point.Item1].Length)
      map[point.Item1][point.Item2] = '*';

  // The string we want to output; 
  // once again, I prefer Linq solution, but for loop are nice as well
  string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, map
    .Select(line => string.Concat(line)));

  Console.Write(report);
}
```

Finally, all you have to do it to call the methods:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
  UserInput(); 
  PrintMap();

  Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed explanation, you seem to destroy this C# developing :D

Comment: @Benjamin Bajić: I tried to put a real world solution: what should I wrote if, say, my boss had asked me to develop the routine. Vague and *incomplete* (how coordinates are separated: by ',' or by ';' or by space... what if `(-1, -1)` point is provided...)  as well as fickle and *unstable* (I said `20x20`? Nonsence! `45x45`; print out on the Console? Crap! Send me an eMail!) specifications are quite common. User input is another concern: "I have tried putting `1 ; 2` point for an hour, please, help me out!".